# How to use AsyncLocalStorage to log in Winston WITHOUT express

Tags: node.js, local-storage, winston

I'm new on nodeJS and I'm working on a project which exposes some REST services.

Now I want to be able to add the unique identifier of the request to each log line so that I can correctly trace all related actions.

I'm using winston to log everything in my app. This is how my logger.js looks

```
const { createLogger, format, transports } = require('winston');
const { combine, json, splat, timestamp } = format;
const logLevel = process.env.LOG_LEVEL || 'info';
const logger = createLogger({
  level: logLevel,
  format: combine(timestamp(), splat(), json()),
  defaultMeta: { 
    service: 'my-service',
    'Transaction-Ref-Id': 'HERE SHOULD BE TXNREFID'},
  transports: [new transports.Console()],
  silent: process.env.NODE_ENV === 'test',
});
module.exports = logger;
```

I want to have a "Transaction-Ref-Id" which will be involved in all the functions and actions that are being called when the client calls for example a POST service API.

I have read a lot about that and I found a lot of examples using some plugins and talking about AsyncLocalStorage but in all the examples I found always they are using express framework. I can not use express framework(it's not allowed for this requirement) so I have to search a way to do it without that framework.

I have another file to create the transactionId, something like this:

```
module.exports.findOrCreateTxnRefId = (event) => {
  
  const txnRefIdFromClient = event.headers
    ? event.headers['Transaction-Ref-Id']
    : event.headers;
  const { requestId } = event.requestContext;
  const txnRefId = txnRefIdFromClient || requestId;
  logger.debug({
    message: 'Transaction-Ref-Id',
    details: txnRefId,
  });
  event.headers['Transaction-Ref-Id'] = txnRefId;
  return txnRefId;
};
```

I want to create a unique transactionId and after that set it in defaultMeta from logger.js in that way all my logs which belongs to a request would have the same transactionId.

After all I expect something like this:

```
{"Transaction-Ref-Id":"HERE SHOULD BE TXNREFID","details":"hello","level":"debug","message":"Hello2","service":"my-service","timestamp":"2023-06-14T22:18:57.271Z"}
{"Transaction-Ref-Id":"HERE SHOULD BE TXNREFID","details":"NoAuth","level":"debug","message":"clientId","service":"my-service","timestamp":"2023-06-14T22:18:57.271Z"}
{"Transaction-Ref-Id":"HERE SHOULD BE TXNREFID","level":"error","message":"Transaction validation failed: 'transactions' field is missed or empty","service":"my-service","timestamp":"2023-06-14T22:19:00.018Z"}
```

Comment: any luck with this (with or without express)? I'm currently in a similar situation needing something like this.